# How to open url with opera in incognito mode?

Tags: python, browser, subprocess, opera, incognito-mode

This is the code that opens opera in incognito, but I have no idea how to open URL in incognito.

```py
import subprocess
command = '"C:\\Users\\Igor\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Opera\\launcher.exe" --private'
subprocess.Popen(command)`
```

Could anyone help me with this? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Tested on Windows 10 Pro

If you need only to open your opera in private mode, you can use `subprocess.run`:

> `subprocess.run` was added in Python 3.5 as a simplification over `subprocess.Popen` when you just want to execute a command and wait until it finishes, but you don't want to do anything else meanwhile.

To open URL by command line, you have to use `--remote <url>` parameter

So, your code can look like this:

```py
import subprocess


def run_opera_private():
    cmd = r'C:\Users\Igor\AppData\Local\Programs\Opera\launcher.exe --private --remote <url>'
    #example cmd=r'C:\Users\karol\AppData\Local\Programs\Opera\launcher.exe --private --remote google.com'
    subprocess.run(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    run_opera_private()
```

If you are using python < 3.5, replace `subprocess.run` with `subprocess.Popen`